# Using the word tutoring

Tags: word-order

What structure is correct:

> 1) Voluntarily tutoring a group of struggling high-school students Chemistry and Biology

or

> 2) Voluntarily tutoring Chemistry and Biology a group of struggling high-school students.

I have a feeling that the first one is right, yet I'd like to hear you opinion.

Comment: Neither one is correct, because you tutor someone **in** a subject, but the first one is closer to being correct.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to add that while I agree, "*in* Chemistry and Biology" is the most correct for the first one, the way it is written now is OK, too, in informal contexts.

Comment: And I'd probably say "Tutoring a group...as a volunteer" or "Volunteer-tutoring...." To me, saying "voluntarily tutoring" sounds a bit snooty (at best) and almost as if it could have been non-voluntary. But this may be a cultural thing. Perhaps there is a lot of compulsory tutoring where you live? Is this for a resume or an application of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are

> Voluntarily tutoring a group of struggling high-school students **in** Chemistry and Biology.

or

> Voluntarily tutoring Chemistry and Biology **to** a group of struggling high-school students.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions raises two points. One point is the syntax of "teaching" and "tutoring." Another point is the need for a grammatical subject in a sentence.

The following sentences are all correct.

- He was teaching biology.
- He was tutoring biology.
- He was teaching biology to a group of students.
- He was tutoring a group of students in biology.

This sentence is wrong, but changing "tutoring" to "teaching" would fix it:

- He was tutoring biology to a group of students.

Also wrong, for a mixture of reasons:

- He was tutoring biology a group of students.

These are wrong because they do not have grammatical subjects. You could fix them by adding (to the front) words like "He was" (and making the "V" a lower-case v):

- Voluntarily tutoring a group of students.
- Voluntarily tutoring Chemistry and Biology.